# I use a stored procedure to set three variables, but it only sets one and ignores the other two statements

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, session-variables

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Snowflake (via DBeaver) that sets a series of variables that can be used while writing SQL code. The idea is that my team will use this code to create session variables that are standardized across projects. I'm a little new to stored procedures in Snowflake, so I have been taking this in small steps and starting with just three variables. It runs without errors when I call the procedure, but it only sets the first variable.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test(startdate DATE,endate DATE, finalcohort VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
$$
BEGIN
SET dt_begin = startdate;
SET dt_end = endate;
SET coh = finalcohort;
END;
$$;
```

When I call the code, it runs fine but only sets the startdate session variable:

```
CALL sp_test('2016-01-01','2016-12-31','somecohort');
```

Here is what I get when I execute SHOW VARIABLES; after calling the procedure:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4gNL.png)

```
session_id    |created_on             |updated_on             |name    |value     |type|comment|
--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------+----------+----+-------+
7301714791026 |2022-04-06 13:27:13.127|2022-04-06 13:27:13.152|DT_BEGIN|2016-01-0l|date|       |
```

Why aren't dt_end and coh being created?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple assingnment at once:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test(startdate DATE,endate DATE,
                                    finalcohort VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
BEGIN
SET (dt_begin,dt_end, coh) = (:startdate,:endate,:finalcohort);
END;
$$;

CALL sp_test('2016-01-01','2016-12-31','somecohort');
```

Check:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

Output:

[image]

Version with single assignment also works `SET dt_begin = startdate;` should be `SET dt_begin = :startdate;`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test(startdate DATE,endate DATE,
                                    finalcohort VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
BEGIN
SET dt_begin = :startdate;
SET dt_end = :endate;
SET coh = :finalcohort;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the same result. I tried both ways, even copying and pasting your code. I'm still only getting the one variable.

I'm running this in Amazon WorkSpaces, DBeaver version 21.1.5 (I know, out of date, but I'm forced to use it in this environment.) The system is running Windows Server 2016.

Comment: This is weird - If I change the order of the variables in the procedure, I get the expected result.

SET (coh,dt_begin,dt_end) = (:finalcohort,:startdate,:endate);

Why would that matter?

Comment: @CatalpaSuz Strange, I have run the code in Snowsight and everything works as it should in both cases. Are you sure in both cases the variables exists in context of the same session? `SELECT CURRENT_SESSION()` should be the same for the one that calls procedure and the one that tries to use it